# Rename files after entries in a list

Tags: python, list, rename

I need to rename a few files systematically. So I have a list of names I want the file names to rename in. The folder consists of `wav` files, that are named like:

```
VP01.wav
VP02.wav
VP03.wav
```

The order in the `ID_list` is already the right order. So basically I want that `VP01` will be `01_a`, `VP02` will be `03_a`, etc. I tried to do it like this:

```
ID_list = ['01_a', '03_a', '04_b', '01_b', '05_a', '04_a', '03_b']

import os
path = glob.glob('filepath\*.wav')
for item in path, ID_list:
    os.rename(item, item)
```

But it gives me:

```
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

as error. The files I want to change are `wav` files.
Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Please add complete error details.

Comment: Please add enough information for someone else to re-create the problem.

Comment: even if it wouldnt create an error you would rename the same file multiple times which doesnt make sense

Comment: Please provide error details

Comment: You need to provide `os.rename` with the original names of the files you want to rename. Were you expecting the function to guess which files to operate on?

Comment: I changed the Code using glob for refering to all single wav files in the given directory

Comment: Can you post a sample list of source files, the expected new names, and how do you decide which new name it will have?

Comment: You can get pairs of corresponding items from two lists with `zip(list1, list2)`. See the `zip` function's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path("path_containing_wav_files/")
path = file_path.glob('**/*.wav')

for en, x in enumerate(path):
    x.rename(ID_list[en] + '.wav')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this gives me a TypeError: glob() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pattern'

Comment: my bad. fixed it.

Comment: Now the error is: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: It gives me again an AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'iterdir'

Comment: `.iterdir` is a method available for Path class. Looks like we need to use `path` here instead. hope it works.